# NestJS + SQS + @ssut/nestjs-sqs - SQS receive message failed: Could not load credentials from any providers

Tags: typescript, nestjs, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to setup a sqs consumer in nestjs using the package `@ssut/nestjs-sqs` but I'm having some troubles. When I start my application I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npdz8.png):

My setup:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.9.3",
    "@graphql-tools/utils": "^10.0.6",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^12.0.9",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.2.6",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.2.6",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^12.0.9",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1",
    "@ssut/nestjs-sqs": "^2.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1473.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "graphql-tools": "^9.0.0",
    "prisma": "^5.3.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
```

My GitHub repository for example and tests: https://github.com/KozielGPC/rls-prisma-postgres-example/tree/add-aws-sqs

Tried to run the application with the code on the repo, and expect to work correctly and receive the message from the SQS queue without bugs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.